# JAXB not able to convert value into BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

In a Spring Boot application I am using **maven-jaxb2-plugin** to generate classes from WSDL file:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>AUTODETECT</schemaLanguage>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <generatePackage>pl.pantuptus.app.integration</generatePackage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The WSDL file contains **sales** field defined as:

```
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="sales" type="s:decimal" />
```

which is transformed by **maven-jaxb2-plugin** into a BigDecimal property of a generated class:

```
@XmlElement(name = "sales", required = true)
protected BigDecimal sales;
```

I configure the JAXB Marshaller explicitly in a configuration component:

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("pl.pantuptus.app.integration");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyClient myClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        MyClient client = new MyClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8080/ws");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I call the WS endpoint from the client:

```
getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request)
```

I receive an object with **null** value of **sales** property.

My guess is that JAXB is not able to parse this property correctly because it has comma-based format in the response.

```
<sales>23 771,08</sales>
```

And here comes the question: how can I tell the Jaxb2Marshaller (or any other Marshaller implementation) how to convert such string into BigDecimal?

Comment: I doubt that the given xml value for sales ("23 771,08") is formally valid for the underlying schema. Did you ever validate this input?

Comment: @Heri, thank you for this hint. You are absolutely right, after switching the validation on, the ValidationEventHandler started revealing the truth:
.i.s.w.l.MyValidationEventHandler : LINKED EXCEPTION:  java.lang.NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding validator to the marshaller in **IntegrationConfig**:

```
marshaller.setValidationEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
```

I discovered that the SOAP document (with commas in the sales values) is not validated against the WSDL:

> i.s.w.l.MyValidationEventHandler : LINKED EXCEPTION:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException

I think the only solution for that is to request for a proper WSDL file or for a proper WS response to the service provider.